# Streaming video with kafka and socket communication

Tags: python, sockets, apache-kafka, udp, vlc

Well, basically what im trying to do is to stream a video using vlc. Im passing the video bytes through kafka server and im sending them by socket UDP to a port im my localhost. Ive used wireshark and it says the data is arriving as I can see the size of the data ive been senting. Although, I cant acess the video stream through vlc.

```
import time
import socket
import vlc
import sys
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import numpy as np

TOPIC_KAFKA_SERVER = "TOPIC NAME"
IP_KAFKA_SERVER = 'IP'
PORT_KAFKA_SERVER = '9092'

# INITIALIZE CONSUMER from earliest

consumer = KafkaConsumer(TOPIC_KAFKA_SERVER,bootstrap_servers=[IP_KAFKA_SERVER + ':' + PORT_KAFKA_SERVER], auto_offset_reset='earliest')


#sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM,socket.IPPROTO_UDP)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM,socket.IPPROTO_UDP)


def exibitImages():
    #print('Test later with video using udp://127.0.0.1:37000')
    #i = 1


    for message in consumer:

        #print(type(message),len(message.value))
        sock.sendto(message.value, ('localhost', 37000))
        #print("message sent!")
        """
        if i > 0:
            Instance = vlc.Instance()
            player = Instance.media_player_new()
            media = Instance.media_new('udp://127.0.0.1:37000')
            player.set_media(media)
            player.play()
            i = 0
        """



    #time.sleep(1)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    exibitImages()
```

Basically the problem is with the socket udp. The kafka is working well. I cant acess the video streaming with vlc.

Comment: VLC offers a wide range of streaming options, so, why Kafka?

Comment: well, kafka is being used to send the video in bytes from another computer. I´m designing a survaillence camera system. So we will need different computers receiving data from the same server and sending to the same server. Kafka works better on managing this flow.

Comment: Kafka is a distributed message broker. Your data is going to be distributed across partitions. You cannot expect global ordering. Therefore, It is better you find a different solution to stream the video.

Answer (score 0):

update: I can acess the data in bytes that has been sent to me. The video runs fine when I save it as a .ts file and run in the vlc or any other media player. Although, what i really wanted was to acess via stream network in vlc through the udp://127.0.0.1:PORT